# Proving that a specific kernel is positive definite

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, eigenvalues, kernels, integral-operators

*Most theoretical papers concerning kernels assume that they are given a positive definite kernel. In this question, we want to show that a specific kernel is positive definite.*

We are interested in the following kernel defined for $0\leq x,y \leq 1$:
$$K(x,y) = (x+y)^{3/2} - |x-y|^{3/2}.$$
Numerical simulations have shown that this kernel is positive definite, that is, for all non trivial $\phi : (0,1) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, we have the following inequality:
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 K(x,y) \phi(x) \phi(y) > 0.$$
Can this fact be proved? Where should I look for references?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We show below a slightly more general claim (to simplify notation, I'll write only in terms of matrices).
$\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}$

**Def.** We say a kernel $\psi: X \times X \to \reals$ is *negative definite* (nd) if $\sum_{ij}c_ic_j\psi(x_,x_j) \le 0$ for all $c$ such that $\sum_i c_i = 0$.

> **Lemma.** Let $\psi$ be cpd. Fix some $x_0 \in X$. Then, $$k(x,y) = \tfrac12[\psi(x,x_0)+\psi(y,x_0) - \psi(x,y)-\psi(x_0,x_0)]$$ is positive definite.

*Proof.* Lemma 2.1 in [Harmonic analysis on Semigroups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387909257), by  van den Berg, Christensen, Ressel (BCR)

> **Corollary.**  Let $0 \le \alpha < 2$. Then, $$k(x,y) := (x+y)^\alpha-|x-y|^\alpha,$$ is a positive definite kernel on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

*Proof.*  First, observe that $-(x+y)^\alpha$ is nd (Corollary 2.11, BCR). Also, $|x-y|^\alpha$ is nd (Thm. 2.2, BCR). Consider, now $$\psi(x,y) = -(x+y)^\alpha + |x-y|^\alpha.$$

Using the lemma above it follows that $$k(x,y) = \psi(x,0)+\psi(y,0) - \psi(x,y)-\psi(0,0) = -\psi(x,y)$$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thank you very much for this precise answer and this awesome reference. I will definitely read (BCR) thoroughly.

Comment: You're welcome! That book is great, you'll enjoy it.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this. I have read (BCR) and I think I understand the proofs. My initial question included a strict inequality. I am having a hard time proving it, because I think one cannot derive the strict positivity of an integral operator from properties of the matrices. Indeed, working on matrices implies that you must take some kind of a limit to recover results on the integral operator. And, of course, this limit will not preserve any kind of strict inequality you may have obtained on the matrices.

Comment: Indeed, proving strict positive definiteness requires more work (apparently, I only read the first sentence of your original question and the formula for the kernel function but did not notice the strict inequality!) Once I get a chance, I'll try to update with pointers that may help in establishing the strictness.

Comment: $-(x+y)^\alpha$ is nd when $\alpha \in [1,2]$ only, right?